# opencv dft only working correct for image dimensions with a power of 2

Tags: image-processing, opencv, fft, dft

I am currently experiencing a strange behaviour with dft function in opencv. I am dft forwarding some opencv matrices and doing some calculations in the frequency domain and afterwards I am transforming it back again.

The outcome looks as expected for images with a dimension in the power of 2 (e.g. 256x256, 512x512) but I get complete nonsense for any other dimensions.

My code looks roughly like this:

```
cv::Mat Z(Pgrads.rows, Pgrads.cols, CV_32FC2, cv::Scalar::all(0));

cv::dft(Pgrads, P, cv::DFT_SCALE | cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
cv::dft(Qgrads, Q, cv::DFT_SCALE | cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

/* doing some calculations */

cv::dft(Z, Z, cv::DFT_INVERSE | cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
```

The operation I am doing is called photometric-stereo, so in short I am doing a global integration over some gradients. Has anybody else experienced this problem with opencv and can give me some advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

FFT only works with power-of-2 size data sets

It's normal to expand the images and pad them with a constant value (which has no effect on the fourier result) see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html

Comment: I know that opencv dft is doing a fft if and only if the image has power-of-2 dimensions and a regular dft in any other case, but that doesn't explain why I am getting strange results.

Answer (score -2):

It's not at all true that FFTs only work with power of 2 data sets. With OCV's particular implementation, they claim (as of 2.4.9) that it works with other sizes but that the power of 2 padding is just recommmended for efficiency. You will find very old FFT libraries that have the 2^N limitation, but I haven't seen one for a long time. You might make sure you're using the current version (I know as of the date of the asking, OCV had more or less the current FFT implementation) and not some really old code.
I don't know how you're evaluating the output, but most likely the problem is that you're giving it a complex input CV_32FC2 while using a flag that tells it to expect a real input, DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT. DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT means "take a real input and give me the full, unpacked complex output rather than the CSS form." I have no idea what the code tries to do if you mix that flag with a complex input. You might also make sure you're initializing the imaginary part of your input to 0, since you're using real image data. At any rate, you should probably be using CV_32FC1 inputs for the images instead of CV_32FC2.